# How to show server.port in intellj idea Services tool bar

Tags: java, intellij-idea

i want to see server.port like this
[image]

what should i add to configuration?  [image]

Comment: What would you like the name of the run configuration to be while the app is not running and `server.port` doesn't have a value?

Comment: @Jeff Scott Brown servises are running, server on 8081, client server.port=0, it written in application.properties

Comment: Please report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with a small sample project to reproduce this problem.

Comment: "servises are running, server on 8081, client server.port=0, it written in application.properties " - I understand.  I am asking what you would like the name to be when the server is not running.

Comment: @Jeff Scott Brown it no matter the name, i want to see in what server.porn app is running